# Can I do GroupBy in the query to avoid property in poco class?

Tags: .net, sql, linq, poco, dto

I have 4 tables in db:

```
- News (NewsID(PK), NewsCategoryID(FK), NewsType (FK), NewsFormatID(FK), Caption, Description)
 - NewsType (NewsTypeID (PK), Caption)
 - NewsCategory(NewsCategoryID (PK), Caption)
 - NewsFormat (NewsFormatID (PK), Caption)
```

I have 2 POCO objects:

```
public class News
{
    public int NewsID { get; set; }
    public int NewsTypeID { get; set; }
    public int NewsFormatID { get; set; }
    public string Category{ get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class NewsCategory
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public List<News> News{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to make a query to return List. In the query I want to group News by their Category. I did it like this:

```
public static List<NewsCategory> GetNews()
    {
        using (var tc = new NewsDataContext())
        {
            var dc = tc.DataContext;
            var newsQuery= (from news in dc.News
                          join newsCategory in dc.NewsCategories on news.NewsCategoryID equals newsCategory.NewsCategoryID
                          join newsType in dc.NewsTypes on news.NewsTypeID equals newsType.NewsTypeID
                          join newsFormat in dc.NewsFormat on news.NewsFormatID equals newsFormat.NewsFormatID
                          select new News
                                     {
                                         NewsID = news.NewsID,
                                         NewsFormatID = newsFormat.NewsFormatID,
                                         Caption = news.Caption,
                                         Description = news.Description,
                                         Category = newsCategory.Caption
                                     });

            return newsQuery.GroupBy(item => item.Category).Select(item => new NewsCategory
                                                                             {
                                                                                 Caption = item.Key,
                                                                                 News= item.ToList()
                                                                             }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

..and this is working. My question here is, can I remove NewsCategory property from POCO class News and do the grouping by category directly in the query (after joins) and how ??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a NewsCategory property in the News POCO and have it lazy/explicitly loaded.

Check out [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) post for more details.

Comment: I am using Linq2Sql. Any other ideas? I still want to group news by category in the db and have List<NewsCategory> where Caption from NewsCategory is property I want news to be grouped by.

Answer (score 1):

This code demonstrates how to load row/column data and shape it after the query is executed.  It does not "group by in the database", but it does allow the removal of the News.Category property.

```
var query= (
from news in dc.News
from newsCategory in news.NewsCategories
let newsFormat = news.NewsFormat
select new //anon type
{
  NewsID = news.NewsID,
  NewsFormatID = newsFormat.NewsFormatID,
  Caption = news.Caption,
  Description = news.Description,
  Category = newsCategory.Caption
});

//Load anon rows
var rows = query.ToList();

//shape the anon rows into our POCSO's.
List<NewsCategory> result = rows
  .GroupBy(item => item.Category)
  .Select(g => new NewsCategory()
  {
    Caption = g.Key,
    News = g.Select(row => new News()
    {
      NewsID = row.NewsID,
      NewsFormatID = row.NewsFormatID,
      Caption = row.Caption,
      Description = row.Description
    }
  })
  .ToList();

return result;
```

---

There is a reason you don't want to "group by in the database".  The database behavior of group by is to return key and aggregates.  You want key and group elements.  In order to get the group element for each group, linqtosql will requery the database with the keys of each group.  That leads to many roundtrips (known as the n+1 problem, where n is the number of groups and +1 is the query to get the keys).

The `Enumerable.GroupBy` method returns group keys and elements - which is exactly what you want.

Comment: If I understood, in order to remove the News.Category property I have to make anonymous type object, group by category and then bind to proper POCO?

Comment: well, you don't -have- to use anon object.  You could declare that object too.  It's two mappings (query mapping type -> query result type -> POCO)